# Why it is not changing the heigth and width of the button

Tags: flutter

```dart
InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
    onTap: () {},
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 25,
      width: screenWidth *65,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Text(
          'Confirm',
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 15,
             color: Color(0xff000000),
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
           ),
         ),
       ),
      ),
```

Comment: Hi Amartya, welcome to StackOverflow. 
You seem to not be using a button in your code. Do you want to make a custom button, or does a RaisedButton or FlatButton work for you?
Is there a specific reason you want to use the screenWidth do define the width of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
  width: double.infinity,
  child: FlatButton(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
    ),
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    onPressed: () => print('pressed'),
    child: Text('Confirm',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: Color(0xff000000),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
      ),
    )
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SizedBox` widget as it not of any issue in your current widget tree anyway as you are using container already

and use those `height` and `width` parameter inside `container` widget

try this

```
InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
    onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        height: 25,
        width: screenWidth *65,    
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Text(
          'Confirm',
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 15,
             color: Color(0xff000000),
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
           ),
         ),
     ),
```